# Alternating row colors except for duplicates

Tags: css

I've got a sticky situation I need some help with:

I need help coming up with a rule to style alternating background colors, ***except*** if there are duplicates of an element, in which case those need to be the same color, without affecting the subsequent elements.

Here's a preview of what that looks like

```html
<section> a </section>               
<section> b </section>               
<section class="dupe"> c1 </section> 
<section class="dupe"> c2 </section>
<section class="dupe"> cn </section> 
<section> d </section>               
<section> e </section>
```

Here's what we're given:

- This solution needs to be in css.
- The duplicates will all have the same class.
- I'm not allowed to group these things under another `<div>` to make things easier.
- There will only be one group of duplicate, being the `section c`'s
- As of right now for the current implementation, `section c` only has a single duplicate of itself (so just `c1` and `c2` at this point), but there's no guarantee that it will stay that way in the future. I mention this in case there are no solutions, and we have to resort to coding just for the 2 at this point.
- There's also no guarantee that the `section c`'s will always be odd (we might add another section before it which will make `section c`'s even). So we might need a rule for if it's odd and if it's even as well.

Some researching suggested that using the general sibling `~` selector might help, but I could only use that to solve half of the problem, which is making them all the same color.

```css
  section {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  section:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: red;
  }
  section:nth-of-type(even) ~ .dupe {
    background-color: red;
  }
  section:nth-of-type(odd) ~ .dupe {
    background-color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<section> a </section>               
<section> b </section>               
<section class="dupe"> c1 </section> 
<section class="dupe"> c2 </section>
<section class="dupe"> c3 </section>
<section class="dupe"> cn </section> 
<section> d </section>               
<section> e </section>
    
d should be red but it's not, because it's 7th (odd)
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share your Html too? From the code I guess the wrapper will be having the `.dupe` class right ?

Comment: I'm sorry, it was my first time doing a code snippet so I accidentally broke it. I've fixed it now, I think . . .

Comment: So, is it fixed now ?

Comment: To answer your question. If by "wrapper" you mean `<section>` then yes, all the `<section>` wrappers that will be duplicates will be given a `.dupe` class

Comment: The code snippet is fixed so you can view my attempt at the problem, but the problem is still not solved ^^"

Comment: In the question, you mentioned `d should be red but it's not, because it's 7th (odd)`, but 7th one is odd and the background-color you specified for odd is `blue` :|

Comment: I understand that, but that's just how far I've gone with the solution. I don't know what else I can do to make it work.

Comment: Can I know how you are appending the `dupe` class to the duplicate items in the list ? Is the list dynamic and you are appending the list using JS/Something ?

Comment: Yep, I've got a function that knows if a `<section>` needs to be given a `dupe` class to them.

Comment: Will there be multiple sets of duplicated elements?

Comment: Nope, just `section c`. I'll add that to the given list

Comment: Then can't you append a class name (blue/red) based on its successor who is the base section? Considering `c` is the 3rd item and the next 4 items will be its duplicates, so since it is 3rd item, you can append `blue` to all those duplicates instead of `dupe` class. Would that solve your issue

Comment: No unfortunately, I wish I could give more context, but I can't do that, and so that's why I'm looking for a css solution T_T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main logic with this solution is to check whether the first dupe element is followed after an odd element or an even element with a combination of `:not()` and the general sibling selector `~`. Brief explanations can be found in the comments.

```css
section:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: red;
}
section:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}
.dupe ~ section:nth-of-type(even) {                      
  /* elements after .dupe */
  background-color: blue;
}
.dupe ~ section:nth-of-type(odd) {                       
  /* elements after .dupe */
  background-color: red;
}
section:nth-of-type(even)+.dupe:not(.dupe ~ .dupe) {     
  /* style first .dupe by seeing whether it is immediately next to an even section */
  background-color: blue;
}
section:nth-of-type(even)+.dupe:not(.dupe ~ .dupe) ~ .dupe {
  /* style subsequent .dupe by seeing whether the first .dupe is immediately next to an even section */
  background-color: blue;
}
section:nth-of-type(odd)+.dupe:not(.dupe ~ .dupe) {
  /* style first .dupe by seeing whether it is immediately next to an even section */
  background-color: red;
}
section:nth-of-type(odd)+.dupe:not(.dupe ~ .dupe) ~ .dupe {
  /* style subsequent .dupe by seeing whether the first .dupe is immediately next to an even section */
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<section> a </section>               
<section> b </section>    
<section class="dupe"> c1 </section> 
<section class="dupe"> c2 </section>
<section class="dupe"> c3 </section>
<section class="dupe"> cn </section> 
<section> d </section>               
<section> e </section>
```

```css
section:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: red;
}
section:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}
.dupe ~ section:nth-of-type(even) {                      
  /* elements after .dupe */
  background-color: blue;
}
.dupe ~ section:nth-of-type(odd) {                       
  /* elements after .dupe */
  background-color: red;
}
section:nth-of-type(even)+.dupe:not(.dupe ~ .dupe) {     
  /* style first .dupe by seeing whether it is immediately next to an even section */
  background-color: blue;
}
section:nth-of-type(even)+.dupe:not(.dupe ~ .dupe) ~ .dupe {
  /* style subsequent .dupe by seeing whether the first .dupe is immediately next to an even section */
  background-color: blue;
}
section:nth-of-type(odd)+.dupe:not(.dupe ~ .dupe) {
  /* style first .dupe by seeing whether it is immediately next to an odd section */
  background-color: red;
}
section:nth-of-type(odd)+.dupe:not(.dupe ~ .dupe) ~ .dupe {
  /* style subsequent .dupe by seeing whether the first .dupe is immediately next to an odd section */
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<section> a </section>               
<section> b </section>               
<section> c </section>
<section class="dupe"> d1 </section> 
<section class="dupe"> d2 </section>
<section class="dupe"> d3 </section>
<section class="dupe"> dn </section> 
<section> e </section>               
<section> f </section>       
<section> g </section>
```

Comment: This makes so much sense to me! Thank you so much!